# Can I Extend the Swap in macOS?

Tags: macos, swapfile

I have a 2017 model of Macbook Pro 13-inch with 8 Gigs of RAM. I want to have some "extra" memory by using swap, because I want to create some virtual machines that need lots of memory. I have read that swap file in macOS is only 1 GB. Can I extend the swap file as much as I want ?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/207641/how-can-i-increase-the-maximum-allowed-swap-space

Comment: here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-can-i-move-virtual-memory-swap-files-to-a-different-drive-or-partition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Swapfiles under /private/var/vm are system managed.

[Apple Support - How can I increase swap size](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7417584?answerId=7417584021#7417584021)